# iPad Take Photo changes orientation

Tags: ipad, cordova, orientation

I am developing a PhoneGap app for iPads with a landscape-only orientation and I have run into a problem that I can't seem to figure out. In the app is a feature that allows you to take a photo of a customer. If you take and crop the photo in landscape mode, it looks like it tries to change the orientation of the app to portrait (I get a black bar on the right side). However, if you take and crop the photo in portrait mode, the app stays in landscape. You can even take the photo in landscape and crop it in portrait and the app will maintain its landscape orientation. I now assume that the problem lies in whatever happens when I click "Use" in the crop screen (Move and Scale screen). Does anyone know what could be causing this or how to fix it? Thanks.